# Comparing between two JavaScript Objects/Arrays values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

There is something unclear for me which I would like to ask you. 
Let's say I have 2 API's calls. 
One returns with array:

```
array1 = [H, 3, 2]
```

Second returns with object:

```
array2 = [
{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1},
{0: 'p', 1: 2, 2: 4},
{0: 'r', 1: 2, 2: 2},
{0: 'h', 1: 2, 2: 3}   ];
```

How do I compare between the twos values? For example array2[4]'s values are H, 2, 3 which equal to array1's values H, 3, 2 but in a different order. 
How can I compare the values only and not its order and get boolean result as true once found in array2 values which equal to array1. By the way, I am using Angular + TypeScript.

Hopefully someone can assist me with the issue.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Return a boolean there is a match? Get the index of the match?

Comment: something wrong in your array2

Comment: Have you tried or researched anything? I mean, multiset-equality is not exactly a new concept.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yes, I did researched but none was between object and array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of ways of doing it, easiest in my opinion is to sort it and join it and do a string comparison.

```js
array1 = ['h', 3, 2]

array2 = [
  {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
  {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1},
  {0: 'p', 1: 2, 2: 4},
  {0: 'r', 1: 2, 2: 2},
  {0: 'h', 1: 2, 2: 3}
];

var test = array1.sort().join()
var result = array2.some(obj => Object.values(obj).sort().join() === test)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working now!!!
I feel a bit stupid not using sort, cause I did manage to use all except that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = ['h', 3, 2];
let array2 = [
  {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1},
  {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1},
  {0: 'p', 1: 2, 2: 4},
  {0: 'r', 1: 2, 2: 2},
  {0: 'h', 1: 2, 2: 3}
];
function compare(a1, a2) {
  for (i in a2) {
    if (a1.sort() === Object.values(i).sort()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(compare(array1, array2));
```